# Problem with characters encoding in bash in 12.04 new install?

Tags: command-line, bash, utf-8

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04.4 64 bits, all seemed to be ok, when I started to work on console I noticed:

- that I couldn't get some accented characters typed in to the console, for example, if I tried to type *é* I would get a *?*
- That neither a `ls` or any other unix commands output would display such characters properly.
- *ANSIX3.4-1968* appeared as default character encoding in terminal, so:

  - I changed the character encoding to UTF-8 at *Set Character Encoding* option in Terminal menu. I can type these special characters properly but can't get other commands to output in a correct way. And I have to change this every time I open a new console.

When I install anything I see this among the outputs and log info:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "es_MX.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Also if I do a typo at any command working from console I get:

```
Sorry, command-not-found has crashed! Please file a bug report at:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/command-not-found/+filebug
Please include the following information with the report:

command-not-found version: 0.2.44
```

My settings at install were only English language and Spanish Keyboard layout. What could it have happened? And how can I fix it *permanently*?

Comment: Oddly on 14.04.2 (linux-image 3.16.0-41-generic) I have the exact same problem.  The context is somewhat different though as `$ locale` yields: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8    
LANGUAGE=en_US:en_AU:en_CA:en_GB:en_NZ:en   
LC_CTYPE="C"    
LC_NUMERIC="C"    
LC_TIME="C"    
LC_COLLATE="C"    
LC_MONETARY="C"    
LC_MESSAGES="C"    
LC_PAPER="C"    
LC_NAME="C"    
LC_ADDRESS="C"    
LC_TELEPHONE="C"    
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"     
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"    
LC_ALL=C    `
I am sure the key is to change one of those parameters to st more tolerant of accents. Report.